# All considered symbols in validator.js?

Tags: validation, express-validator, validator.js

I use the .isStrongPassword() function from validator.js. By default it checks if the password contains at least one symbol. Unfortunately I can't find a set of all the chars that are considered a symbol by validator.js. Also generally there does not seem to exist a uniform opinion/definition about that. So now I am a little confused. Any help/opinions highly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for validator.js? I'm guessing this is it: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/#readme

Answer (score 1):

By looking in the code for validator.js, found [here](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isStrongPassword.js), this is the regex used for the symbols:

```
/^[-#!$@%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/ ]$/
```

So, all of the US standard keyboard characters are used, including a space:

```
- # ! $ @ % ^ & * ( ) _ + | ~ = ` { } [ ] : " ; ' < > ? , . /
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).